# jQuery to replace Flash slideshow with text

Tags: jquery, html

I'm wanting to replicate the slideshow on this website. I have the simple transitions working, but am having trouble adding in the text. Is it possible to animate specific text for each slide? If so how?

http://argusrad.com/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would strongly recommend using `TweenMax` to recreate any Javascript animations that you want to imitate from flash.

This is because `TweenMax` was created in `Actionscript` first. It follows a familiar api so should you encounter tweens in flash you will be able to get a good approximation in JS.

Have a look: http://www.greensock.com/get-started-js/